# Django initiates a DetailView instead of a ListView contrary to what is defined in urls.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I came across a very strange behavior of my django app, that I don't understand. Maybe someone sees an obvious mistake, that I don't see. I also must admin, I am not an expert in django...
I have a Model - `Exposure` and my app `app_name = 'BPMWebGUI'`
A User can have Exposures and I am using the default django User model.

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.user_login, name='user_login'),    
path('<slug:slug>/', views.ExposureDetailView.as_view(), name='exposure_detail'),
path('my_exposures/', views.ExposureListView.as_view(), name='user_exposure_list'),
]
```

The link `href="{% url 'BPMWebGUI:user_exposure_list' %}` works and url: *127.0.0.1:8000/BPMWebGUI/file_upload/* appears in the browser

```
views.py

from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import Http404
from .models import Exposure, User

class ExposureDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Exposure

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print("Exposure Detail View initiated")
        super(DetailView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class ExposureListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Exposure
    template_name = 'BPMWebGUI/user_exposure_list.html'

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print("Exposure List View initiated")
        super(ExposureListView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            print('get query set is called')
            self.exposure_user = User.objects.prefetch_related('exposures').get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print("I was here")
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.exposure_user
```

And when I run the code in debug mode I end always in the `__init__()` of ExposureDetailView and not in ExposureListView. If I want to see the details of some Exposure I do get into the DetailView correctly. Can someone help, or is the information given not sufficient? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_exposures` is a valid slug. Django can't know that you weren't using it as a slug but meant it to go to the list view. You can fix this by swapping the order of your URL patterns:

```
path('my_exposures/', views.ExposureListView.as_view(), name='user_exposure_list'),
path('<slug:slug>/', views.ExposureDetailView.as_view(), name='exposure_detail'),
```